# How to change menu hover color to white on my theme?

Tags: css

When you look at my themes menu, you can see when you hover over the menu links, the hover color is red. That is good. What you can also see is that the link inside the red hover turns from white to black. I would like to keep it white and do not know how to approach it.

http://yourtechadvisors.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go in your style.css line 18 and delete the "color" attribute for `#navigation .sf-menu > li.sfHover > a` and the one for `#navigation .sf-menu > li > a:hover`. Alternatively, you can set it for `color: white`